# override :first-child pseudo class styling using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to override the defined :last-child style defined in my stylesheet using jQuery. 
I'm aiming for minimal markup using a combination of css and jQuery where the structure around "container-content" is appended to the div on document-ready.

```
<div id="title-some-impact"><!--Vertical container title--></div>
   <div class="container-content-wrapper">
         <div></div>
         <div class="container-content"><!--Actual container content-->
            <div class="sub-container-content"></div>
         </div>
         <div style=""></div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using the first and last div in container-content-wrapper to add rounded corners using css, like so:

```
.container-content-wrapper>div:first-child {  /* rounded corners top */
    width: 930px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(../Images/top-rounded-corners.png) top no-repeat;
}

.container-content-wrapper>div:last-child { /* rounded corners bottom */
    width: 930px;
    height: 33px;
    background: url(../Images/bottom-rounded-corners.png) top no-repeat;
}
```

In some cases I need to change the bottom background image using jQuery / JavaScript have failed miserably so far.

I've tried using:
    $('.container-content-wrapper>div:first-child').css('background', 'some other link');
Also, adding another class that points to another image does not work.

How can I override the defined :last-child style defined in the stylesheet using jQuery?

Comment: Can you please show your full jQuery handler where you try and load the background? And also, how do you load your jQuery, in an external .js file or in a `<script>` tag inside your html?

Comment: What I'm getting at here is I think your image path might be wrong in the jQuery.

Comment: I was experimenting with firebug and initially sceptic, but the url to the image was indeed the issue! Shame on me for not checking it better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container-content-wrapper>div:first-child').css('background', 'some other link');
```

That selector is fine with your markup. It will select that first `div` which is a direct ascendant from `.container-content-wrapper`. So that is not your problem.

CSS selectors have no reference to jQuery selectors, so you cannot "overwrite" them. It looks like your `some other link` is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I initially made a mistake in targeting the div whose style needs to be replaced. It was just a matter of making the correct selection.

For reference, I have solved it by using:

```
$('.container-content-wrapper:has(.sub-container-content)')
.addClass('container-content-wrapper-for-sub');
```

where container-content-wrapper-for-sub has this style **and** is defined below .container-content-wrapper>div:last-child

```
.container-content-wrapper-for-sub>div:last-child {
/* rounded corners bottom for subsection */
    background: url(../Images/bottom-rounded-corners-extra-gray.png);
}
```